# How do I put my initial state to use in my reducer file?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, debugging, redux, react-redux

Whenever the user clicks `<Button/>`, inside the database it stores it as  `FIRST_PERSON_CHOSEN`

Instead of `somebody` (as per `reducer.js` file).

I would like to make use of the `initialState` in the `reducer.js` file because as of now, it might as well not even be there-it's not doing anything.

Inside `Main.js`, the `personPlacedInFirebase()` function which holds `() => this.firstPersonChosen()` is firing `FIRST_PERSON_CHOSEN` and not `somebody`.

How do I make this happen?  If additional information is required, please let me know & I'll post it.

Here's my `Main.js` file:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { connect } from 'react-redux';

import Modal from 'react-modal';    
import Aux from '../../../../hoc/Aux';
import Button from '../Buttons/Button';
import CheckoutButton from '../../../../components/UI/buttons/CheckoutButton/CheckoutButton';

import { FIRST_PERSON_CHOSEN } from "../../../../store/action/PersonChosenAction";     
import { CLOSE_MODAL, OPEN_MODAL } from "../../../../store/action/NoNameAction";

class Main extends Component {    
    componentWillMount() {
        Modal.setAppElement('body');
    }

    personPlacedInFirebase() {
     axios.post('./chosen.json', this.props.firstPersonChosen())
        .then(response => {
            console.log("person placed check firebase");
        }).catch(error => {
        console.log(error);
    })
}

    render() {
        return (
            <Aux>
                <Button clicked={() => this.personPlacedInFirebase()} label={"This button"}/>               

                <CheckoutButton clicked={() => this.props.openModalRedux()}/>

                <Modal isOpen={this.props.isOpen}>
                 <p>{this.props.thisButtonChosen}</p>
                    <button onClick={() => this.props.closeModalRedux()}>Close</button>
                </Modal>
            </Aux>
        );
    }
}

const mapStateToProps = state => {
    return {
        isOpen: state.global.isModalOpen,
        clicked: state.personChosen.differentPeople
    }
};

const mapDispatchToProps = dispatch => {
    return {
        firstPersonChosen: () => dispatch({type: FIRST_PERSON_CHOSEN}),

        // Modal handlers
        openModalRedux: () => dispatch({type: OPEN_MODAL}),
        closeModalRedux: () => dispatch({type: CLOSE_MODAL})

    }
};
```

Here's my `reducer.js` file:

```
import React from 'react';
import * as actionTypes from '../action/FIRST_PERSON_CHOSEN';

const initialState = {
    personName: ' '
};

const personChosen = (state = initialState, action) => {
    switch (action.type) {
        case actionTypes.FIRST_PERSON_CHOSEN:
            return {
                ...state,
                personName: 'somebody'
            };
    }
    return state;
}

export default personChosen;
```

Comment: It seems for Main.js file you missed to include FIRST_PERSON_CHOSEN constant from action types.

Comment: @samee I have FIRST_PERSON_CHOSEN where it says: `firstPersonChosen: () => dispatch({type: FIRST_PERSON_CHOSEN})`.

Comment: in reducer.js you did import `import * as actionTypes from '../action/PersonChosenAction';` and then in switch case you used `actionTypes.FIRST_PERSON_CHOSEN`.  As FIRST_PERSON_CHOSEN is a constant so in `firstPersonChosen: () => dispatch({type: FIRST_PERSON_CHOSEN})` how `FIRST_PERSON_CHOSEN` will be available? cz its neither defined nor got import in Main.js.

Comment: @samee ah yes, I did, I somehow missed that one.  I just changed my original posts code.  that's a typo on my end.  It still doesn't work even with the imports.

Comment: If you notice in this line `axios.post('./chosen.json', this.props.firstPersonChosen())` the second param which is the call to dispatch action `this.props.firstPersonChosen()` will not return you the object, it will just dispatch the action to the reducer. So in `axios.post('...url',{name:'somebody'})` you should explicitly pass the value that you want to save in database and on success in `.then(response => { .....` dispatch reducer action.

Even you can save initial in a common file as you did for constants. So initial sate will be reusable.

Comment: ok I got it, that works.  I see `somebody` in the database.  I changed it to `axios.post('...url',{personName:'somebody'})` But when you say   `.then(response => { .....` dispatch reducer action, right underneath `.then`  I  wrote `dispatch({type: FIRST_PERSON_CHOSEN})` but I can get an error that says `dispatch is undefined`.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/177654/discussion-between-sp92-and-samee).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you notice in this line

```
axios.post('./chosen.json', this.props.firstPersonChosen())
```

the second param which is the call to dispatch action

```
this.props.firstPersonChosen()
```

will not return you the object, it will just dispatch the action to the reducer.

So in

```
let name = 'somebody';
axios.post('...url',{name})
```

you should explicitly pass the value that you want to save in database and on success you dispatch the action to reducer. You can also pass the name if you want to update the application state.

```
.then(response => this.props.firstPersonChosen(name))
```

If you are passing the name param to firstPersonChosen the update its definition in mapDispatchToProps so it will accept the name as param and can pass further to reducer.

Note: You can also save the initial in a common file as you did for constants. So initial sate will be reusable.